# Test code coverage is 50% in brances using Istanbul for Mocha test. How to make it 100%?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, istanbul, enzyme

New to writing unit test cases.Code Coverage is 50% in branch using istanbul for react code with testing - MOCHA + CHAI + ENZYME. Not able to figure out what's missing in the code.

**subscription.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Subscription extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {

super(props);
this.state = {
  input:'',
}
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();

this.setState({
 input: ''
})
}

handleChange(e) {
this.setState({
  input:e.target.value
})
}

render() {

  //Setting up className here
  //let inputSel = this.state.isChecked?"active":"";

  return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="email" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.input} />
            <button className="buttonStyle">Subscribe</button>
          </form>
        </div>
  );
 }

 } //end of class
```

**app.js:**

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {render} from 'react-dom';
  import Subscription from './Subscription'

  class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <Subscription />
      </div>
  );
  }

   }


   render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

**test.js**

```
        import React from 'react';
        import sinon from 'sinon';
        import {mount,shallow} from 'enzyme';
        import { expect } from 'chai';

        import Subscription from '../src/client/app/Subscription'



        describe('<Subscription />', function() {

          before(function() {
            it('should have subscription component',function(){
              expect(shallow (<Subscription />)).to.have.length(1);
            });

          });



          it('should have a form ',function(){
            const wrapper = shallow (<Subscription />);
            expect(wrapper.find('form')).to.have.length(1);
          });
          it('should have an input box with type email', function() {
            const wrapper = shallow (<Subscription />);
            expect(wrapper.find('input[type="email"]')).to.have.length(1);
          // expect(wrapper.find('.subscribeinput')).to.equal(true);

          });
          it('should have a button', function () {
            const wrapper = shallow(<Subscription />);
            expect(wrapper.find('button')).to.have.length(1);
          });
          it('input and button should be child of form',function(){
            const wrapper = shallow (<Subscription />);
            expect(wrapper.find('input').parent().is('form')).to.equal(true);
            expect(wrapper.find('button').parent().is('form')).to.equal(true);
          });

          it('should have an initial email state', function () {
            const wrapper = mount(<Subscription/>);
            expect(wrapper.state().input).to.equal('');
          });
          it('should update the src state on changing input', function () {
            const wrapper = mount(<Subscription/>);
            wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'hello@ifelse.io'}});
            //wrapper.setState({ input: (wrapper.find('input[type="email"]').value()) });
            expect(wrapper.state().input).to.equal('hello@ifelse.io');
          });
          it('should update the input box on subscribe', function () {
            const handleSubmit = sinon.spy();
            const wrapper = mount(<Subscription/>);
            wrapper.find('button').simulate('submit', { preventDefault() {} });
            expect(handleSubmit).to.have.been.called;
            expect(wrapper.state('input')).to.equal('');
          });

        });
```

** Result of Coverage summary using Istanbul **

**Coverage summary**
Statements   : 100% ( 9/9 )
Branches     : 50% ( 1/2 )
Functions    : 100% ( 1/1 )
Lines        : 100% ( 9/9 )

why is branches alone 50%? what should be done to make it 100%?

Comment: There is no branching at all in the code you provided, so I'm not sure how you managed to even get coverage for one branch. The only branching logic you have in your non-test files is commented out.

Comment: not sure why i have got such results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ongoing issue with Istanbul and ES6 syntax.  The super call is being picked up as a branch.

One workaround is to place this comment block right beneath super(props):

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
```

I have still yet to find a proper solution as I am not keen on littering my source with ignore blocks.

source: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/690